# How to set value/css to ASP button from code behind without using runat=server in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, input

i have an `HTML Button` as:

```
 <asp:Button id="Button2" Text="Edit" class="but" runat="server"/>
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Add" class="but" />
```

now, i want to set "display:none" to `Add` button when Click on `Edit` from code behind in

asp.net. without applying `runat="server"` to `Add Button`.

Help appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: why use <asp:Button> if you don't want runat="Server">

Answer (score 3):

You will need to do several things in order to achieve this.

1. Create a property in your code behind that has the style you wish:

   ```
   public string AddButtonStyle { get; set; }
   ```
2. Use this in your markup for the button:

   ```
   <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Add" class="but" 
                                              style="<%:AddButtonStyle %>" />
   ```
3. Set this style accordingly in the button click event:

   ```
   AddButtonStyle = "display: none;";
   ```

You may want to initialize the property to `string.Empty` on page init.